# How do I label US state borders in ArcMap 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, cartography, labeling

I'm trying to label a border between TN and NC, but the label manager won't let me. How can I get it to work? I'm using ArcMap 10.1[image: Red circle is where I want the label to go]

Comment: What are your maplex settings?  Most often you want to use an interval and then convert dynamic labels to static annotations and place manually.

Comment: Based on your other labels, I would guess that that boundary is too windy for it to figure out how to do a straight label so close to the boundary line.  If you have spline set, I'm not sure why it's not displaying.  ArcMap can make some interesting decisions sometimes when it comes to dynamic labeling.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this by playing with the label properties or using other label engines but the easiest in this case would probably be go to layout mode and just create a text box and label the feature.  Make sure to match your fonts from the other labels.

If you are dead set on having the label spline along the border check out this

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help./index.html#//00s80000001v000000.htm

Again there are other ways to do this but for one label the quickest and least painful method is as described above